# In ReactJS how do I keep track of the state of a group of checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to keep track of which boxes are checked in my local state(you can check multiple boxes). I want to be able to check and uncheck the boxes and keep track of the ids of the boxes that are checked. I will do something with the values later. This is what I have so far:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import './App.css'
    import  CheckBox  from './CheckBox'


    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          fruits: [
            {id: 1, value: "banana", isChecked: false},
            {id: 2, value: "apple", isChecked: false},
            {id: 3, value: "mango", isChecked: false},
            {id: 4, value: "grape", isChecked: false}
          ],
          fruitIds: []
        }
      }

      handleCheckChildElement = (e) => {
        const index = this.state.fruits.findIndex((fruit) => fruit.value === e.target.value),
          fruits = [...this.state.fruits],
          checkedOrNot = e.target.checked === true ? true : false;
          fruits[index] = {id: fruits[index].id, value: fruits[index].value, isChecked: checkedOrNot};
          this.setState({fruits});
          this.updateCheckedIds(e);
        }

      updateCheckedIds = (e) => {
        const fruitIds = [...this.state.fruitIds],
            updatedFruitIds= fruitIds.concat(e.target.id);
          this.setState({updatedFruitIds});
      }

      render() {
        const { fruits } = this.state;
        if (!fruits) return;

        const fruitOptions = fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
          return (
            <CheckBox key={index}
              handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement}
              isChecked={fruit.isChecked}
              id={fruit.id}
              value={fruit.value}
            />
          );
        })

        return (
          <div className="App">
          <h1>Choose one or more fruits</h1>
            <ul>
            { fruitOptions }
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App
```

So basically I am able to check and uncheck the boxes, but I cannot seem to update and store the fruitIds. Here is my checkbox component also:

```
    import React from 'react'

    export const CheckBox = props => {
        return (
          <li>
            <input key={props.id}
              onChange={props.handleCheckChildElement}
              type="checkbox"
              id={props.id}
              checked={props.isChecked}
              value={props.value}
            />
            {props.value}
          </li>
        )
    }


    export default CheckBox
```

Also if you have a cleaner ways to do this than the way I am doing it, I would love to see it.

Comment: You can take a look at this example of how to handle multiple checkbox that I did last time : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-controlled-checkbox-list-ejlfn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @frootloops can you confirm that this has a value `e.target.id` console.log it to see its content.

Comment: @harisu I console logged it and I have access to e.target.id.

Comment: I have provided another approach as an answer for which I could take to do it.  However, let me see if we can debug your current code.

Comment: some few errors I find in your code are inside `updateCheckedIds` function you are using updatedfruits to update state but it's not existing and never used. there are various ways of optimizing your code like you could simply inside your `updateCheckedIds` function do this `this.setState({fruitsIds: [...this.state.fruitsIds, e.target.id]})`

Comment: which can go further to completely eliminate the need for that function if you take the suggested logic above inside the `handleCheckChildElement` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what if I were to approach it I will do. I will create a one dimensional array that holds the id's of the fruits when A fruit if clicked(checked) I will add it id to the array and when its clicked the second time I check if the array already has the id I remove it. then the presence of id in the array will mean the fruit is checked otherwise its not checked  So I will do something like below

```
  this.state={
    fruitsIds: []
   }
  handleCheckChildElement=(id) => {
//the logic here is to remove the id if its already exist else add it. and set it back to state
   const fruitsIds = this.state.fruitsIds;
    this.setState({fruitsIds: fruitsIds.contains(id) ? fruitsIds.filter(i => i != id) : [...fruitsIds, id] })
   }
```

then I render the checkboxes like

```
    <CheckBox key={index}
     handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement}
     isChecked = { this.state.fruitsIds.contains(fruit.id)}
     id={fruit.id}
   />
```

This is because you can always use the id to get all the other properties of the fruit so there is absolutely no need storing them again.
then the  checkbox component should be as follows

```
export const CheckBox = props => {
    return (
      <li>
        <input key={props.id}
          onChange={() => props.handleCheckChildElement(props.id)}
          type="checkbox"
          id={props.id}
          checked={props.isChecked}
          value={props.value}
        />
        {props.value}
      </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: I got it all working now. Just to clarify your answer for other viewers, I just had to change ```.contains()``` to ```.includes()``` in both places, use ```e``` as the param in the ```handleCheckChildElement``` function, and  ```e.target.id``` instead of just ```id```.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting your ids updated because:

1. You are trying to concat a non array element to an array.
   `concat` is used for joining two or more arrays.

   > updatedFruitIds = fruitIds.concat(e.target.id);
2. You are not updating your actual `fruitIds` state field. I dont know why you are using "updatedFruitIds" this variable but due to above error it will always result into a single element array.

   > this.setState({ updatedFruitIds });

```
  updateCheckedIds = e => {
    const fruitIds = [...this.state.fruitIds],
      updatedFruitIds = fruitIds.concat([e.target.id]);
    this.setState({ fruitIds: updatedFruitIds });
  };
```

OR

```
  updateCheckedIds = e => {
    const fruitIds = [...this.state.fruitIds, e.target.id],
    this.setState({ fruitIds });
  };
```